# Trigger Sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace trigger t1 
  before update of price on book 
declare 
  vdif number; 
begin 
  vdif:=:new.price-:old.price; 
  dbms_output.put_line('Price Diff is '||vdif); 
end;
```

I'm getting this error:

> NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't use `:new` or `:old` in a table-level trigger.  You need a row-level trigger.  So you'd need to add `FOR EACH ROW` to your declaration

```
create or replace trigger t1 
  before update of price on book 
  for each row
declare 
  vdif number; 
begin 
  vdif:=:new.price-:old.price; 
  dbms_output.put_line('Price Diff is '||vdif); 
end;
```

Of course, in reality, you'd never write a trigger that just wrote to the `dbms_output` buffer (nor would you write production code that depended on anyone seeing anything written to `dbms_output`).  But I assume that you are a student and you're just doing this as part of a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger you wrote is a **table level** trigger, and table level triggers fire once for each operation on the table. So, for example, if you had a query that updates multiple rows, the trigger would be called just once so :new and :old doesn't know what row to affect.

What you actually want is to add a `FOR EACH ROW` clause in the trigger definition (under "before update..."), which will make your trigger a **row level trigger** and it will fire for each row you are updating.